# how to use default wordpress header and footer in static html page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress website located "public_html" folder and I uploaded a static HTML page name facts.html to a new folder in public_html/nutritionfacts, let say its very simple like:

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1> FACTS </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I add the default website header and footer to new static html page? and if I have 1000 static pages what is the best way to do it.

Comment: The best way is to create new pages directly in wordpress. So each page gets headers, footers, menus etc. So intead of oploading html pages to your webserver, use [the built-in functions of WP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8je71.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need all those pages in .php extension add the following native function `get_header` `get_footer` on all those static pages and your header and footer will appear.

**facts.php**

```
require '../../wp-load.php';

<?php get_header(); ?>

   echo "<html>
    <body>
    <h1> FACTS </h1>
    </body>
    </html>";

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: I did this but show error msg "This page isn’t working xxx.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: You also need to require this file require '../../wp-load.php'; at the top of your facts.php file. This wp-load.php file should be located in wordpress root folder.

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: Add this code in the top of your facts.php to see errors. Thanks

Comment: thank you very much. its working now. but I think no need to use echo".....;. you can write it direct as html